# Paypal sandbox error: Things doesn't appear to be working at the moment

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to set up subscription based payment with the below code

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://example.com/subscribe/ipn">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="TY3URFFH8DYDN">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Everything works up until after buyer login. The resulting error:
[image]

Comment: PayPal frequently has problems with their sandbox. This isn't your problem, it's theirs.

Comment: This is a sandbox account configuration problem, likely an unconfirmed email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the receiving account has a confirmed email in the sandbox environment: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessmanage/account/accountOwner

The sandbox environment never sends "real" emails, so you don't need to check a real email inbox to get to the confirmation message.  Instead, go to the developer "[Notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/notifications/)" tab. ("Log into dashboard" in its upper right, if you haven't already)

---

(If you haven't imported this particular www.sandbox.paypal.com account to your live developer.paypal.com login yet, do so first via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Faccounts%2F -> log in to portal -> use first link on the page to authenticate with the sandbox account's credentials to link it.)